# Trying to understand how .id(_:) works in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use `.id(_:)` to do some programmatic scrolling with a ForEach, such that a Form will scroll each time a new section is added to it using the ForEach. However, I am getting some undesirable behaviour and I would like to understand the mechanics of what is causing said behaviour. As you can see in the screenshot, the third text view isn't even showing up. When I remove the `id` method, all three Text views show up as you'd expect.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array: [Int] = [1]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { p in
            NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(self.array, id: \.self) { num in
                    Section {
                        Text("Hello")
                        Text("My name is slim shady")
                        Text("number \(num)")
                    }
                    .id(num)
                    .onChange(of: array.count) { count in
                        p.scrollTo((count + 1), anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button("add") {
                        array.append(array.count + 1)
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues going on here. I have never tried to put a `Section` inside a `ForEach` like that, but they obviously do not play well. I removed it and used a `VStack` instead. I am not sure if you can make new sections like that, but that is another question for another day.

The issue you were having with your `ScrollTo` is a misunderstanding of what  `id` you were actually using. When you instantiate a `ForEach` with an array that is not otherwise identifiable, you use `.self` as the `id`. However, that means you are keeping track of the elements themselves, not the contents of each element. So, when you tried to put an `int` into your `scrollTo()`, nothing happened because an `int` is not an element of your array. What you need to do is supply an element like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array: [Int] = [1]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { p in
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    ForEach(self.array, id: \.self) { num in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Hello")
                            Text("My name is slim shady")
                            Text("number \(num)")
                        }
                        // num is an element of your array, not an int
                        .id(num)
                        .onChange(of: array.count) { count in
                            // Supply scrollTo with an array element here
                            p.scrollTo(array.last, anchor: .top)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button("add") {
                            array.append(array.count + 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply Yrb. I've spent a lot of time thinking about your comment... I don't actually think what you mentioned was the issue. I looked at my code again and I had made a small mathematical error with the argument I passed into `scrollTo`; it should have just been count. After I fixed that, it started working, although as you mentioned creating sections inside of the `ForEach` is still causing an issue. Thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone happens to read this, after a bunch of experimenting I have been able to make this work. It appears as though the issue that I posted in my screenshots was being caused by creating sections inside of the `ForEach`, as Yrb mentioned. However, I tried a different initializer for creating sections and it seems to work as long as you provide a view for the section header. I have no idea why however, if anyone has any insight please share.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array: [Int] = [1]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { p in
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    ForEach(self.array, id: \Int.self) { num in
                        Section {
                            TextVeiwshg(num: num)
                        } header: {
                            Text("section #\(num)")
                        }
                        .id(num)
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button("add") {
                            array.append(array.count + 1)
                            print(array)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: array.count) { count in
                print(array.count)
                withAnimation {
                    p.scrollTo((count), anchor: .top)
                }
                print("scrolling to \(count)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```